# Transcendental Functional Equations

Tags: functional-equations

Given $f^k(x) = f \circ f \circ f\circ ...(x)$ composed $k$ times,

Do the functional equations $f^k(x) = g(x)$, where $g(x)$ is a basic transcendental elementary function, for example, the inverse hyperbolic trigonometric functions, have elementary solutions?

e.g. $f \circ f (x) = \sinh^{-1}(x) $

This question was raised by a friend of mine with a well developed understanding of (Australian?) high-school mathematics, and some fundamentals of applied mathematics (e.g analysis), but not much else, so try to be as clear as this situation allows it.

Comment: What about the equations? Are you asking if they have a solution?

Comment: oh, whoops, missed out on that lol. added in

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_square_root) will be of interest to you